# Vue.js use return value from method called in template

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'd like to use the value returned from a function called inside my template.

template:

```
<div class="director">
    {{ fetchDirector(movie.imdbId) }}
</div>
```

vue.js:

```
async fetchDirector(movieId) {
    try {
        await axios.post(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${movieId}&apikey=...`)
        .then((res) => {
            return ( res.data.Director )
        })
     } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
     }
}
```

I can't figure out how to display the [object Promise] value `fetchDirector(movie.imdbId)` gives.. Thank you!

Comment: you can fetch the director on vuejs mounted, and store the director in the data?

Comment: I need to get a different director for many different elements

Answer (score 1):

```
.then((res) => {
  return ( res.data.Director )
})
```

This arrow function in your example returns the value, but it has no effect on anything. Instead of returning from this function, define a `data` property on your component, (named for example `director`), and then, instead of returning from this arrow function, assign the fetched value to the data property like this:

```
data () {
  return {
    director: ''
  }
},
mounted () {
  axios.post(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${movieId}&apikey=...`)
    .then(res) => {
      this.director = res.data.Director;
    })
}
```

And render the value in your template:

```
<div class="director">
  {{ director }}
</div>
```

Comment: It seems great but I need to use `movieId` as I am fetching for several elements that need their own `director` name. How can I do it?

Comment: I do not have lot of time at the moment, but could you make the children components themselves handle the fetch? This way you would just move the `mounted()` hook to the children themselves, and set the data property in them directly.

Comment: @Wizzardzz have you tried what I suggested ? How did it go ?